# Endpoint of Brownian motion conditional on high maxima

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, large-deviations

*Note: This question is closely related to an earlier question: [A large noise limit](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417015/a-large-noise-limit).*

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion.

For every $\varepsilon > 0$, let $A_\varepsilon$ denote the event

$$\{\underset{0 \leq t \leq 1}{\text{max}} W_t  \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\} \;, $$

and let $\mathbb P^\varepsilon$ be the probability measure given by

$$P^\varepsilon (E) = \frac{\mathbb P(E \cap A_\varepsilon)}{\mathbb P(A_\varepsilon)} \;, $$

for all measurable events $E$.

We denote by $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P^\varepsilon}$ the expectation under $\mathbb P^\varepsilon$.

**Question:** Is it true that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \mathbb E_{\mathbb P^\varepsilon} \big [\lvert \varepsilon W_1 - 1 \rvert \big ]= 0?$$

Comment: This conditional distribution is a well known consequence of the reflection principle, and easy to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\vpi}{\varphi}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$Yes, this is true:

By the reflection principle (see e.g. [Proposition 2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/aca1518a09539a09ddd37428ab0d0268_MIT15_070JF13_Lec7.pdf), for $M:=\max_{0\le t\le1}W_t$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &P(M\ge1/\ep,W_1\in dx) \\ 
    &=P(W_1\in2/\ep-dx)1(x<1/\ep)+P(W_1\in dx)1(x>1/\ep) \\ 
    &=\vpi(2/\ep-x)1(x<1/\ep)dx+\vpi(x)1(x>1/\ep)dx, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\vpi$ is the standard normal pdf.

So,
\begin{equation}
    P(A_\ep)=P(M\ge1/\ep)=2G(1/\ep)\sim2\ep\vpi(1/\ep),
\end{equation}
where $1-G$ is the standard normal cdf, and
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &E1(M\ge1/\ep)|\ep W_1-1| \\ 
    &=\int_{\mathbb R}P(M\ge1/\ep,W_1\in dx)|\ep x-1| \\ 
    &=2\big(\ep\vpi(1/\ep)-G(1/\ep)\big)=o(\ep\vpi(1/\ep)) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
(as $\ep\downarrow0$).
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\de(\ep):=  E_{P_\ep}|\ep W_1-1|=\frac{E1(M\ge1/\ep)|\ep W_1-1|}{P(A_\ep)}\to0. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}

---

The expression for $\de(\ep)$ in \eqref{1} can be rewritten as follows:
\begin{equation}
\de(\ep)=\frac\ep{r(1/\ep)}-1, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
where $r:=G/\vpi$ is the Mills ratio. Then one can use known asymptotic expansions of and bounds on the Mills ratio (see e.g. [this paper](https://eudml.org/doc/122588)) to get asymptotic expansions of and bounds on $\de(\ep)$.
For instance, from Propositions 1.3 and the simplest two cases of formula (1.8) (with $m=1,2$) of that paper we get
\begin{equation}
    \de(\ep)=\ep^2 - 2 \ep^4 + 10 \ep^6 - 74 \ep^8 + 706 \ep^{10}+O(\ep^{12})
\end{equation}
(as $\ep\downarrow0$) and
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\ep^2}{1 + 2 \ep^2}<\frac{\ep^2 + 7 \ep^4}{1 + 9 \ep^2 + 8 \ep^4}
    <\de(\ep)<\frac{\ep^2 + 3 \ep^4}{1 + 5 \ep^2}<\ep^2.
\end{equation}
One may note that the difference between the upper and lower bounds $\dfrac{\ep^2 + 3 \ep^4}{1 + 5 \ep^2}$ and $\dfrac{\ep^2 + 7 \ep^4}{1 + 9 \ep^2 + 8 \ep^4}$ on $\de(\ep)$ is $\dfrac{24 \ep^8}{1 + 14 \ep^2 + 53 \ep^4 + 40 \ep^6}$, which is $<0.00000024$ if $\ep=0.1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Around the same time, Yuval Peres also wrote an answer on a different website. I will be adding his answer too shortly.

Comment: This seems such a remarkable result. Given that the maximum was greater than $1/\epsilon$, the endpoint is within $O(\epsilon)$ of $1/\epsilon$ with high probability via a simple Markov bound (the endpoint $W_1$ is within $100 \epsilon$ of $1/\epsilon$ with probability of more than $.99$). Is it that with overwhelming probability the first hitting time of the maximum is close to $1$ as $\epsilon$ shrinks? That would ensure that $W_1$ cannot fall too far below the maximum value attained (which is $\geq1/\epsilon$), but I struggle to see why $W_1$ can't be $O(1)$ above $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: @user196574 : Yes, $W_1$ must be close to the maximum $M$ with large (conditional) probability -- given what $M$ takes a large value. The entire trajectory $(W_t\colon t\in[0,1])$ will then be close to the linear function $(tW_1\colon t\in[0,1])$, again conditionally on $M$ (or, equivalently, $W_1$) taking a large value. The latter statement follows by (say) the independence of the Brownian bridge $(W_t-tW_1\colon t\in[0,1])$ from $W_1$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis By the way, this latest comment… how does one deal with the fact that we are conditioning on $M$, while the Brownian bridge is only guaranteed to be independent of $W_1$?

Comment: @NateRiver : In that comment, I mentioned conditioning, not on $M$, but on $M$ taking a large value, which I said is equivalent to conditioning on $W_1$ taking a large value. Indeed, if $W_1>b$ for a large $b>0$, then $M\ge W_1>b$. Vice versa, (say) $P(W_1>b/2|M>b)$ will be very close to $1$ of $b>0$ is large -- so that, if $M$ is large, then with an overwhelming probability $W_1$ is large.

Comment: Right understood, I just didn't know how to deal with the integral against Brownian bridge conditional on $M$ taking a large value. (Conditional on $W_1$ itself taking a large value with full probability, this is fine because the Brownian bridge is independent of $W_1$). Hopefully I'm making sense

Comment: @NateRiver : Right, conditioning on $M$ taking large values is almost the same as conditioning on $W_1$ taking large values, because, by the first display in my answer, $P(W_1>b-h|M>b)\to1$ if $b\to\infty$ and $bh\to\infty$, so that (say) $h=\tfrac{\ln b}b$ will do here. Also, trivially, $P(M>b|W_1>b)=1$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Hi, I revisited this again, and wasn’t able to finish your argument. Sorry for the inconvenience, but could you share a bit more details on the conditioning? I understand how to derive that $\mathbb P(W_1 > b - h| M > b) \to 1$ if $b \to \infty$ and $bh \to \infty$, and of course the latter equality $\mathbb P(M > b| W_1 > b)$ is obvious. However I was not able to work out the proper conditioning to deduce the convergence of the sample path from this.

Comment: @NateRiver : Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "the convergence of the sample path".

Comment: Sorry I mean specifically that $\mathbb E[\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |\varepsilon W_t - t| \, | \, \max_{0 \leq t \leq 1} W_t \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}] \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. @IosifPinelis

Comment: @NateRiver : Write $\varepsilon W_t-t=A_t+tB$, where $A_t:=\varepsilon(W_t-tW_1)$ and $B:=\varepsilon W_1-1$. We showed that $E(|B|\,| M\ge 1/\varepsilon)\to0$. Clearly, $E(\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A_t|\,|W_1\ge1/\varepsilon)=E\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A_t|\to0$. I thought that from here it should be rather easy to get $E(\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|A_t|\,| M\ge 1/\varepsilon)\to0$, since the conditioning on $M\ge1/\varepsilon$ is almost the same as the conditioning on $W_1\ge1/\varepsilon$, but I have not checked those details.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to work this out.

Comment: Thanks to your additional details, I was able to work it out. Thank you!

Comment: @NateRiver : Great! I am glad to hear this.

Answer (score 6):

Iosif Pinelis has already posted an answer, but here is an alternate answer communicated to me by Yuval Peres on a different website. Any typoes/mistakes are most definitely mine.

Write

$$\tau = \text{min}\{t > 0 \, : \, W_t \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\}.$$

By the reflection principle, we have

$$\mathbb P(\tau \leq 1) = \mathbb P(A_\varepsilon) = 2 \Phi (-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}),$$

where $\Phi(x) := \int_{-\infty}^x (2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \, dt$ denotes the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

Using the strong Markov property at time $\tau$, we have that $|W_1 - W_\tau|$ is a standard [half normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) random variable with parameter $\sigma = 1 - \tau$, independent of $\mathcal F_\tau$.

Thus we compute

$$\mathbb E \big [|W_1 - \frac{1}{\varepsilon}| \, \big |  \, \tau \leq 1 \big ]$$
$$= \mathbb E \big [|W_1 - W_\tau| \, \big | \, \tau \leq 1 \big ]$$
$$ =  \frac{\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{\{\tau \leq 1\}} |W_1 - W_\tau|]}{\mathbb P(\tau \leq 1)}$$
$$ =  \frac{\mathbb E[\mathbf 1_{\{\tau \leq 1\}} \mathbb E[ |W_1 - W_\tau| \big | \sigma(\tau) ]]}{\mathbb P(\tau \leq 1)}$$
$$ = \frac{\mathbb E \big [\mathbf 1_{\{\tau \leq 1\}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi} (1 - \tau)} \big ]}{\mathbb P(\tau \leq 1)}$$
$$ \leq \sqrt \frac{2}{\pi}.$$

Thus

$$\mathbb E_{\mathbb P^\varepsilon} [|\varepsilon W_1 - 1|] = \mathbb E[|\varepsilon W_1 - 1 | \big | A_\varepsilon] \leq \varepsilon \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

which tends to $0$, as desired.

In fact, the bound above may be further improved as observed by Yuval Peres.

We compute, for any $0 < \delta < 1$,

$$\mathbb P[\tau \leq 1 - \delta \, | \, \tau \leq 1] = \Phi \left ( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1 - \delta} . \varepsilon } \right ) \big  /\Phi \left ( -\frac{1}{\varepsilon } \right ) $$

$$\leq \frac{\text{exp} \big (\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon^2} \big )}{\text{exp} \big (\frac{1}{2 \varepsilon^2 (1 - \delta)} \big )}$$|

where the inequality above is due to the fact that $\Phi(-r) e^{\frac{r^2}{2}}$ is decreasing in $r$.

Thus,

$$\mathbb E \left [ \frac{\sqrt{1 - \tau}}{\varepsilon} \, \big | \, \tau \leq 1 \right ] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(\sqrt{1 - \tau} \geq r\varepsilon \, | \, \tau \leq 1) \, dr$$

$$ \leq \int_0^\infty \text{exp}\big (-\frac{r^2}{2} \big )\, dr = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

And so finally,

$$\mathbb E_{P^\varepsilon} [|\varepsilon W_1 -1|] \leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \varepsilon^2 = \varepsilon^2$$

and this is sharp asymptotically.

Comment: that's nice, can you please provide a link to the website?

Comment: Ah, it is a private mathematics group on Facebook. Here is the link to the group if you are interested: https://www.facebook.com/groups/1923323131245618

Comment: I don't have a Facebook account, so thanks for posting; nice question and nice answers too.

Comment: Thanks, and you're welcome!

Comment: We can also get sharp bounds (sharp of any order) and asymptotic expansions for the conditional expectation in question by using (i) the exact expression for this expectation and (ii) sharp bounds and asymptotic expansions for the MIlls ratio. This remark is now added to my answer.

Comment: Thats extremely sharp indeed. I’ll have to read up on the whole Mills ratio thing, seen it come up quite many times now in your answers.