# Large noise limit for SDE with general volatility coefficients

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion, and let $X$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dX_t = \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t \;, \quad  X_0 = 1 \;.$$

where $\sigma:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a Lipschitz continuous function.

For every $M > 0$, let $A_M$ denote the event

$$\{\underset{0 \leq t \leq 1}{\text{max}} W_t  \geq M\} \;, $$

and let $\mathbb P^M$ be the probability measure given by

$$\mathbb P^M (E) = \frac{\mathbb P(E \cap A_M)}{\mathbb P(A_M)} \;, $$

for all events $E$.

We denote by $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P^M}$ the expectation under $\mathbb P^M$.

Consider the solution to the deterministic ODE

$$dY_t = \sigma(Y_t) \, dt \; , \quad Y_0 = 1.$$

**Question:** Is it true that

$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \, \mathbb E_{\mathbb P^M} \big [\underset{0 \leq t \leq 1}{\sup} |X_t - Y_{Mt}| \, \big] = 0?$$

Comment: What if $t=M^{-1}$ under the supremum, and to be definite, suppose $\sigma(y)=y$?  Then for that value of $t$, we have $X_{1/M} \to X_0 = 1$ while $Y_1 = e$.

Comment: Hm but how do you know the supremum will be achieved at $t = M^{-1}$? I think part of the idea is that this becomes more and more rare as $M \to \infty$. In fact it can be shown that given that maximum event, for every $\delta$ the chance that the supremum occurs within $\delta$ of the endpoint $1$ tends to $1$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you wrote though…

Comment: There is the trivial lower bound $\sup_{0 \le t \le 1} |X_t - Y_{tM}| \ge |X_{1/M} - Y_1|$ for $M>1$, then take expectation, and finally pass to the limit.

Comment: Ah I see. I think conditional on $\mathbb P^M$ we will not have the convergence to $1$, if that makes sense. It certainly converges to $1$, $\mathbb P$-a.s, but not in probability/expectation (relative to the “shrinking” measures $\mathbb P^M$).

Comment: To illustrate maybe I can give a toy example. Take $\Omega = [0, 1]$, $X_\varepsilon = 1_{[0, \varepsilon)}$ and $A_\varepsilon = [0, \varepsilon)$. Then $X_\varepsilon \to 0$ a.s and in $L^1$, but $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P^\varepsilon} [X_\varepsilon] = 1 \not \to 0$.

Comment: The way I understand the conditioning is nicely described in a comment made in https://mathoverflow.net/a/424617/64449, namely that the entire trajectory $(X_t)_{0 \le t \le 1}$ is close to the linear function $t W_1$ conditioned on the Brownian motion taking a large value at $W_1$.  In other words, it behaves like a bridge process which is pinned at $t=0$ to $X_0=1$ and at $t=1$ to $M$.  Therefore, $\lim_{M \to \infty} E_{P^M} |X_{1/M} - Y_1| = |1-e|$, since the bridge satisfies $X_0=1$.

Comment: @Nawaf Bou-Rabee Hm, heuristically what happens when $\sigma(y) = y$ is that the entire trajectory of $W_t$ (not $X_t$!) is close to the linear function $tW_1 \sim Mt$, more boldly one may write $dW_t \sim M dt$, so that $X$ converges to the solution of the deterministic $dX_t = M X_t \, dt$ which has solution $e^{Mt}$, so that $X_{1/M} \sim e$. In fact I think I have proven it rigorously in this particular case $\sigma(y) = y$, though I have not written it up yet…

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true? In the linear case, it seems to me that this would imply that $\mathbb{E}( \sup_{t > 1/2} |W_t - Mt - t/2|\,| \, A_M) \lesssim e^{-M/2}$ which is obviously not the case.

Comment: Hm, by linear do you mean $\sigma = 1$, say? Then this would imply $\mathbb E_{\mathbb P^M} [\sup_{0 < t \leq 1} |W_t - Mt|] \to 0$, which is true. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Nate River By linear I mean $\sigma(x)=x$.

Comment: oh in that case $X$ should converge to $e^{Mt}$, see this post for instance: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425490/solution-to-sde-conditional-on-high-maxima-of-driving-brownian-motion

Comment: @NateRiver Well, you will have $M^{-1} \log X_t \to t$, but the *difference* between $X$ and $e^{Mt}$ will diverge. (Even worse, their ratio won't even converge to $1$.)

Comment: Ah I see your point, the $t/2$ is not negligible…

Comment: @NateRiver Plus, you've got stochastic fluctuations of the same order on top of that.

Comment: You’re absolutely right. Hmm…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, as can be seen in the case $\sigma(u) = u$, so that $X_t = \exp(W_t - t/2)$. For the result to be true, Markov's inequality implies that the law of $W$, conditional on $A_M$, would need to give probability $1/2$ to the event $\sup_{t \le 1}|W_t - Mt + t/2| < K\exp(-M/2)$ for some fixed $K>0$. By large deviations, this event has probability smaller than $c\exp(-c\exp(M))$ for some $c>0$, while $A_M$ has probability larger than $c \exp(-cM^2)$ for some $c>0$, yielding a contradiction.

Comment: You're right, thank you!